# Build Iptables counter

Tags: iptables

If I want to build traffic counter for each IP on Iptables, Which table shall I put the rules in? Mangle, Raw, Nat or Filters?

I used to put it in Filters, but it seem doesn't count correctly

```
iptables -t filter -N COUNT
iptables -t filter -A COUNT -s 192.168.10.10
iptables -t filter -A COUNT -d 192.168.10.10
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -j COUNT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter is the correct table to put the rules in.  If you want help debugging your incorrect counts, you should probably give some details about that.

Comment: I Finally agree with your answer after 4 hours testing and debug between each table. Actually Mangle and Filters are quiet equals in counting.